# Which is preferred -- gcloud sdk or gcloud api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm writing wrappers to create, start, stop GCP services. I can use the gcloud command in a shell script or gcloud-API in a python script. 
I want to know which one is recommended and preferred? Any limitation of one over the other? 
Fluent in both shell and python so language is not a problem. 
One thing I would like to see is the output of the executions and get some information.

Eg: If I create a dataproc, I would like to know the master node and worker node names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question asks for opinions which is not allowed on StackOverflow as there is no one answer for this type of question. Both the Cloud CLI and the Cloud SDK have their strengths and limitations. The CLI is very easy to use, the SDK provides you with raw power. The choice is up to your budget, effort, time investment and overall goals. I would not spend the time to write a Python program to launch one Dataproc cluster only once, I would if I needed to automate this as part of a CI/CD pipleline. However, that is my opinion and opinions vary.

Comment: Thank you, John. I get your point and respect your opinion. I will consider your suggestion and decide one over the other.

Comment: To add to @JohnHanley ‘s comment, you can also rewrite your title and description, so as to remove any inquiry of opinion whilst making the post more technical (what you want to achieve, and any issues in implementing that using the two options you provided).